# How do I install FFmpeg for my bot to play music?

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

I followed a Youtube Tortual on how to make a music bot, and every piece of code made sense, there is just one problem. I thought I installed FFmpeg which is the thingy which makes the bot play audio I believe, the way I installed it was running the following command: pip install ffmpeg

So I waited it to finish up, and attempted to play music, and here is the error message

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shiqi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Shiqi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shiqi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one.
```

Answer (score 1):

Downloading ffmpeg on windows is weird. I struggled with this too when I was writing my first bot. Turns out that the `pip install ffmpeg` installs a *python library called ffmpeg*, rather than installing **actual ffmpeg**(the program your bot needs). Here's how you do it:
[Download a windows build of ffmpeg from gyan.dev (the reccomended way on the ffmpeg website)](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-release-essentials.zip) Once this is downloaded, extract the zip file. Rename the resulting folder to `ffmpeg`, and put it in your `C:\` directory. Then add `C:\ffmpeg\bin\` to your `PATH`. If you don't know how to add something to your `PATH`, let me know and I can explain.

Comment: Is that everything I need to do to install ffmpeg?

Comment: Also I heard of path before, but I don't remember what it is, can you explain it real quick please?

Comment: Yeah no problem . (And yes, this is all you need to do) So  the PATH is a global variable on your PC that any program can access. And what it stores is the locations of programs in your filesystem. This is necessary because if one program would like to use another program, it has to find the code for that program on your hard drive so that it can execute the program.  So when you download ffmpeg, you put the code on your hard drive; adding that location to your PATH makes it so other programs can use it.

Comment: So here's the easiest way to add something to your PATH: press the `windows key` on your keyboard, and then type `env`. As you start typing it, it should show up in the search bar and if you press `enter`, a window should pop up which has a button in the bottom right that says `Environment Variables...`. Click that, and then look to the list of `System variables`. Inside of it you should be able to find something that says `path`. If you double click it, then a list of all of the different values in it should be shown. From here you can add the `C:\ffmpeg\bin\` folder.

Comment: I did that before, and i still have the ffmpeg folder there, however it changed nothing

Comment: Hmm... what happens if you open up command prompt and run `ffmpeg`?

Comment: which command do I run? When I run the music command, it says I need to install ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

As @VintiumDust said, the ffmpeg you installed from the `pip` installer is not the actual ffmpeg, so you will need to install it from the official browser

To get started:

1. Install ffmpeg from its [Official Website](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

You should install it from a respected operating system, lets say you have windows and you will choose windows.

You should see this if you choose windows as a platform to install[image]

I'd recommend downloading ffmpeg from `gyan.dev` as that is the most known sources to install ffmpeg.

After that, you will be redirected to gyan.dev's website for the installer. You need to scroll down until you see this part.[image: H]

Now, which one you're installing is up to you, but I prefer `ffmpeg-git-full.7z` instead, so install that.

2. Extracting and putting the contents of ffmpeg

You should have the zip file by now. Move the zip file to whatever location you want, C: drive is preferred for easier navigation, extract it (It should be `Extract here` for winrar users, not `Extract to ...`), and rename the folder to `ffmpeg`. You can freely uninstall the zip file if you want.

Finally, go inside of the ffmpeg folder and look for the bin folder, you should see it if done correctly, and I recommend copy the path of the bin folder so you wouldn't have to type it all out

[image]

Now for the hard part

3. Putting ffmpeg to the `bin`

Open up Windows menu, type `Enviroment`. you should see this on your search results.
[image]

Open it up and you should see this now.

[image]

At the bottom right that says `Enviroment Variables`, open it up and you should (again) see this.

[image]

(These Environment Variables will also be different than mine but it is okay)

And for the last time, double click the `Path` file and hopefully you would see this.
[image]

(Again, your path variables might be different than mines but that's okay)

Next, press `New` on the right and remember the bin folder path you just copied? Now you have to paste it and press `ok`, you can double check if you have added the bin folder to the `path` variable. if its added, you should be fine, you can now close those windows.

Now to verify that if it exists or not, open up the command prompt and type the following words.

```
ffmpeg -version
```

This will show the version that ffmpeg is on and if done successfully, you should see this popping out :

[image]

If so congratulations! You have installed ffmpeg to your computer! And if it doesn't work, try restarting the computer or reinstall the zip file and putting it to the bin again and see if it helped. thats all really.